# Add column conditionally

Tags: julia

I am trying to add a new column whose values are conditional on other columns.

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta

df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, 
               b = StatsBase.sample([0, 1], 10, replace = true), 
               c = StatsBase.sample([0, 1], 10, replace = true), 
               d = StatsBase.sample([0, 1], 10, replace = true))
@linq df |>
    transform(e = ifelse.(:b == 1 || :c == 1 || :d == 1, 1, 0))
```

But this does not evaluate properly:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
1   1   0   1   1   0
2   2   1   0   1   0
3   3   0   0   0   0
4   4   1   1   0   0
5   5   1   0   0   0
6   6   0   1   0   0
7   7   0   0   0   0
8   8   1   0   1   0
9   9   1   0   1   0
10  10  0   1   1   0
```

Where is the condition wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it (I use `rand` from Base to generate data as it is enough in this case):

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta

df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = rand([0, 1], 10),
               c = rand([0, 1], 10), d = rand([0, 1], 10))
@linq df |>
    transform(e = Int.((:b .== 1) .| (:c .== 1) .| (:d .== 1)))
@linq df |>
    transform(e = ifelse.((:b .== 1) .| (:c .== 1) .| (:d .== 1), "yes", "no"))
```

The issue is that you have to broadcast the operations inside `transform` as `:b == 1` etc. will be always `false`.

I also show that in this case you can simply cast the result to integer using `Int` and `ifelse` is useful if you would want some general values.

Actually in this case probably `@byrow!` is simpler:

```
@byrow! df begin
    @newcol e::Vector{Int}
    :e = :b == 1 || :c == 1 || :d == 1 ? 1 : 0
end
```

---

EDIT. Under DataFramesMeta.jl 0.10 it would be:

```
julia> using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta

julia> df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = rand([0, 1], 10),
                      c = rand([0, 1], 10), d = rand([0, 1], 10))
10×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      d
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      0      1      0
   2 │     2      0      0      0
   3 │     3      0      1      1
   4 │     4      0      1      0
   5 │     5      1      1      1
   6 │     6      1      1      1
   7 │     7      0      1      1
   8 │     8      0      0      0
   9 │     9      1      0      0
  10 │    10      0      1      0

julia> @rtransform(df, :e = Int(:b == 1 || :c == 1 || :d == 1))
10×5 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      d      e
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      0      1      0      1
   2 │     2      0      0      0      0
   3 │     3      0      1      1      1
   4 │     4      0      1      0      1
   5 │     5      1      1      1      1
   6 │     6      1      1      1      1
   7 │     7      0      1      1      1
   8 │     8      0      0      0      0
   9 │     9      1      0      0      1
  10 │    10      0      1      0      1
```

Comment: Awesome. @byrow! is a rather elegant solution in this case. Your [tutorial](https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial) should become the must-read for every Julia data science newbie...

Comment: Has this changed at all in DataFrames 1.3? I commonly need to add a column with values dependent on another col, or on the row number values. Solution by @fc9.30 is fairly convenient.

Comment: The examples in this answer are using DataFramesMeta.jl not DataFrames.jl. Can you provide an example of what you are looking for (best as a separate question) and I can comment how to do it. For now I update the answer to latest DataFramesMeta.jl.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an elegant but simple solution:

```
df[df.a .< 5, :b] .= 2
```

Comment: This is more comprehensible to me, but would like to see this as part of a `transform` or `select`, to incorporate into a pipeline of commands.